# Add link with attributes contained in a row to a table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a row to a table, I can do that, the problem is that the row should contains a link on it and the link should have some parameters. Something like this :

```
 var $row = $("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<div style=\"border-top:3px;padding-top:3px\">" + $("<a>" + result.fileName + "</a>").attr({ href: "/AgencyNotes/OpenFile/" + result.fileName + "/" + result.agencyNoteId }) + "</div>" + "</td>" + "</tr>")

 $(temp).children().children().children().children().first().after($row)
```

I have tried this other code but what I get in la table is just `[object Object]`:

```
var $row = $("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<div style=\"border-top:3px;padding-top:3px\">" + $("<a>" + result.fileName + "</a>").attr({ href: $(".link_open_file").data("url") }).data({"fileName":result.fileName, "noteId":result.agencyNoteId }) + "</div>" + "</td>" + "</tr>")

 $(temp).children().children().children().children().first().after($row)
```

The row is being added correctly but the link is not working, which is the best approach to do this using JQuery? 
By the way this is my controller action:

```
 public ActionResult OpenFile(string fileName, int noteId)
        {
        }
```

I prefer something like the second approach to not harcode the url ...
I'm getting the url from the html page:

```
  @Html.ActionLink(file.FileName, "OpenFile", new { fileName = file.FileName, noteId = file.AgencyNoteId, @class="link_open_file", data_url=Url.Action("OpenFile","AgencyNotes") })
```

Comment: Could you please show as some data? Btw. [object Object] means that you are using object as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you wrote your anchor tag like this:

`"<a href='/AgencyNotes/OpenFile/" + result.fileName + "/" + result.agencyNoteId + "'>" + result.fileName + "</a>"`

In your code:

```
var $row = $("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<div style=\"border-top:3px;padding-top:3px\">" + "<a href='/AgencyNotes/OpenFile/" + result.fileName + "/" + result.agencyNoteId + "'>" + result.fileName + "</a>" + "</div>" + "</td>" + "</tr>")
```

**EDIT:** to include AlexGH's comment for the complete solution:

"It works after I added a new Route to the RouteConfig file, like this:"

```
routes.MapRoute("OpenFile", "{controller}/{action}/{fileName}/{noteId}", new { ontroller = "AGgencyNotes", action = "OpenFile"}, new[] { "Project.Controllers" });
```

Comment: This is working very good but is not hitting for some reason the action controller, I'm getting this link that takes me to a blank page: `http://localhost:56602/AgencyNotes/OpenFile/body_small%20view.docx/7`

Comment: I think the issue may be the file name in your URL, it has the file extension `.docx`. Can you remove the file extension before passing in your `result.fileName`?

Comment: I just want to call the controller to download a file on click, it will not show any url just dowlnoad the file, it should send those parameters to the controller and then download the file, this is my controller and it has two parameters of type string and int I'm not sure why it's not hitting it, I can try to remove the file extension although I would like to keep it to show the file extension in the table  `public ActionResult OpenFile(string fileName, int noteId)
        {
        }`

Comment: The file extension may be fine, is your `public ActionResult OpenFile(string fileName, int noteId)` class empty? Or did you just take out the inner code to show the example? Have you tried debugging to make sure it's not hitting the `OpenFile` action?

Comment: Instead of loading by the fileName, could your `ActionResult OpenFile()` load by the `FileID`, and the `NoteID` instead, and then use that to lookup the filename? Avoiding having to rename the files in your database, if it is the file extension causing the issue.

Comment: I take out the inner code to show the example, I'm setting a breakpoint within the `OpenFile` action but it's not getting hitted, I'm not sure why this approach is good

Comment: It's working now!! If you could add to your answer what I did so future readers will now: your approach was correct, and it works after I added a new `Route` to the `RouteConfig` file, like this:  `routes.MapRoute("OpenFile", "{controller}/{action}/{fileName}/{noteId}", new { ontroller = "AGgencyNotes", action = "OpenFile"}, new[] { "Project.Controllers" });` I will select you as answer just mention the part of the RouteConfig :)

Comment: Awesome! Yeah the route not being set will definitely do it. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var $row = $("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<div style=\"border-top:3px;padding-top:3px\">" + $("<a href='" + $(".link_open_file").data("url") + "'>" + result.fileName + "</a>").data({"fileName":result.fileName, "noteId":result.agencyNoteId }) + "</div>" + "</td>" + "</tr>")
```